# Do humans produce an immune response to their own antibodies?

Tags: immunology, pathology

As far as I know, T and B cells form a part of the adaptive immune response in humans. In their early stages, these cells undergo genetic recombination to produce a diversity of antigen receptors/antibodies, before maturing in the thymus/bone. As a part of this maturation process, I understand that the body presents the lymphocytes the full set of molecules present in the body, and ones evoking an autoimmune response are eliminated. This maturation process allows lymphocytes to recognise the difference between pathogens and body cells/molecules.

My question is this:

> Since the maturing lymphocytes are not exposed to
> pathogen-complementary antibodies before the primary response to a
> pathogen, does the body recognise the variable regions of these newly
> synthesized antibodies as foreign, generating a second wave of
> antibodies?

This might cause the body to produce antibodies it doesn't need to, or unnecessarily remove useful antibodies from the blood by agglutination/phagocytosis.

Comment: Are you asking about anti-antibody antibodies?

Comment: @MattDMo — Seems quite clear to me what the poster is asking. He explained his problem — asking him to put a (your) tag on it is neither required, reasonable nor helpful. If you don’t understand, say what it is you don’t understand.

Answer (score 0):

My naive response it as follows.

The antigen-binding sites on an immunoglobulin are generally concave in shape. Hence I would anticipate that the antigen-binding site on immunoglobulin-1 would have difficulty binding to the antigen-binding site on immunoglobulin-2.

There may be additional considerations, such that the overall difference of the antibody from its un-mutated precursor is too slight to elicit a strong response.